# What is the alternative word to "conservative"?

Tags: american-english

I was reading one of my old posts and I came across the following sentence:

> During my career as a web developer, I encountered many conservative developers.

Is it valid to say: "conservative developer" in English?

I mean the developer who's afraid of sudden or great changes. If not, what is the alternative term then?

Comment: I suggest 'non-innovative'

Comment: @yosef-baskin I think he means "synonym" by "alternative".

Comment: 'unimaginative' is also a possible alternative

Comment: You seem to have the impression that a developer fearing sudden change is a bad thing. Don't many people fear sudden change? What would your *conservative developer* fear: Switching database vendors? Abandoning testing? Developing a floating-point library from scratch? I would fear all of these. So call me conservative. I want to conserve good  things that have served me well.

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/careful

Answer (score 1):

## Traditionalist

> A traditionalist is a person who supports the
> established customs and beliefs of his or her society or group,
> and does not want to change them.
>
> — [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/traditionalist)

You could say "conservative", but it [may wrongly imply a political association](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservatism#:%7E:text=Conservatism%20is%20a%20political%20and,as%20well%20as%20property%20rights.).

Another option: ***orthodox***

> Orthodox—following or conforming to the traditional or generally
> accepted rules or beliefs of a religion, philosophy, or practice.
>
> — Oxford Languages via Google

Comment: *Traditionalist* and *orthodox* also have political and religious overtones, and it is not likely to serve the OP to characterize himself as *unorthodox*, which can connote rebelliousness or carelessness.